# How to add text on mouseover social icon

Tags: html

I would like to know what would be the code to add to have this text: "Vlog Coming Soon" on mouse over the youtube social icon. Thanks

```
[social_icons icon="fa-youtube" size="fa-2x" link="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_self" icon_color="#fff" background_color="#1f1f1f"]
```

Comment: How much research have you done to resolve this on your own?  What have you tried and been unable to get the results you require?

Comment: I tried to find answers, yes. I tried myself in the widget (wordpress), but I add no good results, I decided to ask for help. thanks

Comment: That is fine but you did not show any of the work you might have tried.  That is the reason for the downvotes.  Some people downvote posts that are perceived as "Leaches", ask for help with no real attempt taken.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, I didn't know about that since I am new to this site and my first language is French. Sorry for that !!1

Comment: No Problem...i had to learn the "hard-way" myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just scrapped up quick html / css to give you an idea how this can be done. Basically you'll have an overlay with your text with opacity 0, then when you hover over your social icon, you change the opacity to 1.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

li:hover .overlay-text {
  opacity: 1;
}
li i {
  font-size: 3em !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="social-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <h4>Coming Soon!</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, I will try that. :)

Comment: @IsabelleRoger if it worked for you, can you please check my answer?

Comment: @IsabelleRoger did you literally copy paste my code? Or did you take the idea of how to implement it?